# The Rousseeuw-Croux scale estimators and the Mean Absolute Deviation (MeanAD)

Tags: mad, scale-estimator

The [1993 Rousseeuw-Croux scale estimators](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221996720_Alternatives_to_Median_Absolute_Deviation) were introduced as alternatives to the [Median Absolute Deviation (MedianAD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation), by saying that:

> (1) Of course, there is nothing to stop us from using the MedianAD at highly skewed distributions, but it may be rather inefficient and artificial to do so.

Indeed:

> "the MedianAD correspond to finding the symmetric interval (around the median) that contains $50\%$ of the data (or $50%$ of the probability), which does not seem to be a natural approach at asymmetric distributions."

Moreover:

> (2) The purpose of this article is to search for alternatives to the MedianAD that ca be used [...] in the same way but that are more efficient and not slanted towards symmetric distributions.

If we had the [Mean Absolute Deviation (MeanAD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation), instead of the Median Absolute Deviation (MedianAD) as in their article, would the same arguments mentioned by Rousseeuw and Croux still be valid?

In other words, would the [1993 Rousseeuw-Croux scale estimators](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221996720_Alternatives_to_Median_Absolute_Deviation) be "better" alternatives to the Mean Absolute Deviation (MeanAD) as well?

Or, would the comparison reported by Rousseeuw and Croux make sense only between the Rousseeuw-Croux scale estimators and the Median Absolute Deviation (MedianAD), and not any sense between the Rousseeuw-Croux scale estimators and Mean Absolute Deviation (MeanAD)? This would lead to another doubt: should we always pair the Rousseeuw-Croux scale estimators with the median, or could it make sense to pair them with the mean as well?

In particular, I am interested more on the argument about the skewness of a distribution - i.e. they introduced their estimators since the MedianAD was considered an "artificial" measure for highly skewed distributions -, than on the reasons about the efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

It's good to have more tools in our toolbox. But choosing a tool depends on the task we want to accomplish.

The really thorough way to look at the shape of a distribution is graphically - density plots or quantile plots or box plots etc. But numbers are easier to write. So, for any given problem, we should think about which measure is best. One nice thing about median absolute deviation is that it is very clear what it is. The name itself say it. To me, that makes it *less* artificial than the new measures that the article introduces.

But, just as we *might* want the mean of a skewed distribution, so we *might* want the standard deviation. Going back to the toolbox analogy, we might want a different screwdriver.

Another possibility that I don't see much any more is five- and seven- number summaries (I think Tukey coined these notions in EDA, but my memory could be faulty). And sometimes, only a graph will do.

And sometimes, no measure will do and we will need

Comment: Thanks a lot @Peter!

Comment: You're welcome!  If my answer meets your needs, could you click the check mark to accept it? Thanks!1

Comment: Hi Peter, Yes, I would like to accept your answer, but I am confused.. I mean, I do not understand the relationship between your answer and my question related to the "1993 Rousseeuw-Croux scale estimators" and to the "Mean Absolute Deviation (MeanAD)"........... In particular, I do not understand the connection to the question "If we had the Mean Absolute Deviation (MeanAD), instead of the Median Absolute Deviation (MedianAD) as in their article, would the same arguments mentioned by Rousseeuw and Croux still be valid?"...it might be that I misunderstood your answer :-)

Comment: Maybe, some re-phrase or some additional statement can help to clarify my doubts, maybe? :-) :-)

Comment: My point was that no one method is "better".  It depends on the situation and on what you want to find out.